# Influxdb2 : How to downsample data in a different measurement in same bucket?

Tags: influxdb, downsampling, influxdb-2

I would like to create aggregation measurement into **same bucket** with monthly data. At the moment I have a task with this query:

```
import "strings"

option task = {name: "MTU Monthly", every: 1d}

from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    |> range(start: 1464943523, stop: 1654244985)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "machine_time_utilization")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum)
    |> map(
        fn: (r) =>
            ({r with _measurement:
                    strings.replaceAll(
                        v: r._measurement,
                        t: "machine_time_utilization",
                        u: "machine_time_utilization_monthly",
                    ),
            }),
    )
    |> to(bucket: "my_bucket")
```

I don't like how it is done by using `strings.replaceAll`. Is there a way how to do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set static value in the records, use [set](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/set/) function, ie.

```js
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    ...
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum)
    |> set(key: "_measurement", value: "machine_time_utilization_monthly")
    |> to(bucket: "my_bucket")
```

Comment: It'd be better if to() could do it, because I don't fancy these workarounds with system names, but thank you, this is much better than my solution.